# Trying to get a mouseover event when over a radio button

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to call a function when I mousever a radio button. The function never gets called. The first of my two radio buttons below show my latest attempt.

```
<form action="#">
   <ul>                     
      <li>
         <input type="radio" class="button" name="buttonSubGroup" onclick="Door();" onmouseover="mouseOver('doorMouseover')" onmouseout="mouseOff('doorMouseover')" id="button1" checked/>
         <label for="button1">Door</label>
      </li>
      <li>
         <input type="radio" class="button" name="buttonSubGroup" onclick="Trim();" id="button2" />
         <label for="button2">Trim</label>
      </li>
      <li>
         <input type="radio" class="button" name="buttonSubGroup" onclick="Roof();" onmouseover="mouseOver('roofMouseover');" onmouseout="mouseOff('roofMouseover');" id="button3" />
         <label for="button3">Roof</label>
      </li>
      <li>
         <input type="radio" class="button" name="buttonSubGroup" onclick="Siding();" id="button4" />
         <label for="button4">Siding</label>
      </li>
      <li>
         <input type="radio" class="button" name="buttonSubGroup" onclick="Stone();" id="button5" />
         <label for="button5">Stone</label>
      </li>
      <li>
         <input type="radio" class="button" name="buttonSubGroup" onclick="BB();" id="button6" />
         <label for="button6">BB</label>
      </li>
   </ul>
</form>
```

EDIT:

Here are my JS functions. I put an alert to notify me if I made it into the function.

```
function mouseOver(a) {
    alert(a)
    document.getElementById(a).style.visibility = 'visible';
}

function mouseOff(a) {
    alert(a);
    document.getElementById(a).style.visibility = 'hidden';
}
```

Comment: This seems to work, can you share your javascript?

Comment: Seems to work http://codepen.io/viralpickaxe/pen/aCymG

Comment: Please paste what you've tried for us to know how to help you

Comment: where is your javascript code? please post asap.

Comment: Added Javascript code

Comment: That code seems to work just fine. http://jsfiddle.net/puddinman13/Mh7PZ

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Two things I have noticed:

1.Your checked property on your first radio button should be checked="checked"

2.This code seems to work when hovering over the radio buttons. If you would like it to work when hovering over the label, you will want to add onmouseover and onmouseout event handlers to the labels also. For example:

```
<li>
<input type="radio" class="button" name="buttonSubGroup" onclick="Door();" onmouseover="mouseOver('doorMouseover')" onmouseout="mouseOff('doorMouseover')" id="button1" checked="checked"/>
<label for="button1" onmouseover="mouseOver('doorMouseover')" onmouseout="mouseOff('doorMouseover')>Door</label>
</li>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/puddinman13/Mh7PZ/

Comment: That was it! Thank you much and thank you everyone else!

Answer (score 0):

How are you declaring your functions (mouseOver and mouseOff)?

It could be that it isn't declared in the global scope.
I tried your code [here](http://jsfiddle.net/mailmindlin/4Dv4R/9/), and it seemed to work, except that not all of the radio buttons called mouseOver() or mouseOff().

Try declaring your functions like this:

```
 window['mouseOver']=function(data) {
    //do something
};
window['mouseOff'] = function(data) {
    //do something else
}
```